# Ajax Hover Menu in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

in my web application i am using Hover Menu (ajax) control. I am using two hover menu controls (one hover menu on that second hover menu) it is working fine, i mean the tow hover menus are displaying fine in Mozilla browser and it is not working in IE. can u help me thank you. I mean one hover menu is displaying but sencond one is not displaying on it in IE.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code or a link?

Comment: which version of ajax control toolkit are you using?

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur it is 2.0 version

Comment: Yes i solve the problem my self actually in style shee  i increase the width and height of the panel now it is working fine. Thank you for response to all.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting the Internet Explorer z-index bug - http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/.

Comment: Yes i solve the problem my self actually in style shee  i increase the width and height of the panel now it is working fine, thank you for response @Bermo.